# Multivariate distribution dependence

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Maybe it's a silly question, but I am not quite sure how to calculate a multivariate distribution. Here is what I have:

> Given are $X,Y$ two i.i.d. uniform distributed $U(0,1)$ random
>   variables and $T:=XY$, $Z:=YT$

First I needed to calculate the distributions for $X,Y$ and $T$. I have evaluated them to be 
$$F_{X,Y}=F_X F_Y=\int\int 1_{[0,1]}(x)1_{[0,1]}(y)dxdy=xy$$
$$F_T=\int P(Y\leq \frac{t}{x})f_X(x)dx=\int^t_0 dx+\int^1_t \frac{t}{x}dx=t-t\cdot log(t)$$

But now I need to calculate the multivariate distributions of $X,T$ and $Z,T$.

Now my question boils down to:

Is $T$ dependent or independent of $X$? How about dependence between $Z$ and $T$? I mean, I at least think that they are obviously dependent, but then how do I calculate the multivariate distributions if I cant use $F_{X,T}\neq F_X F_T$? I don't see how to apply the more general statement $F_{X,T}=F_{X|T}F_T$ to this problem.

Can anyone help clear my mind?

Comment: Your question seems to ask how one can compute $F_{X,T}$, that is, to recall some basic definitions, how to compute, for every $(x,t)$, $$F_{X,T}(x,t)=P(X\leqslant x,T\leqslant t)$$ But surely you have some starting ideas to evaluate $$P(X\leqslant x,XY\leqslant t)$$ from the known joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, haven't you? (By the way, let me add that using CDFs instead of PDFs here might only complicate things.)

Comment: Hmm...yeah for $(X,Y)$ I used the fact that they are independent and thus I could just rewrite $F_{X,Y}=F_X F_Y$ but I am not sure if the same holds for $(X,XY)$ though. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Of course "the same" does not hold. But this is not at all what my comment asks...

Comment: Okay, what I know is that $$P(X\leq x, XY\leq t)=P(X\leq x | XY\leq t)P(XY\leq t)$$ Now $P(XY\leq t)$ I have already calculated from previously. The other term is what bothers me...the probability that $X$ occurs given that $XY$ already happend...
btw, a big thank you for your help and patience

Comment: Sorry but this fixation on conditional distributions (which was probably taught to you, unfortunately) only complicates things. Much better to stay with the archi-general definition $$P(X\leqslant x,XY\leqslant t)=\iint\mathbf 1_{u\leqslant x,uv\leqslant t}f_{X,Y}(u,v)dudv$$ which, in your case, yields $$P(X\leqslant x,XY\leqslant t)=\int_0^1\mathbf 1_{u\leqslant x}\int_0^1\mathbf 1_{uv\leqslant t}dvdu=\int_0^{\min(1,x)}\int_0^{\min(1,t/u)}dvdu$$ Now, this is interesting if $0<t<x<1$ (why?) and then the RHS is $$\int_0^x\min(1,t/u)du=\cdots$$ Can you finish?

Comment: Honestly I see this definition for the first time. We defined it with $$P(X\leq x, XY\leq t)=\int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^t f_{X,XY}(u,v)dudv$$ where I see some similarity, but I cant explain why you have $f_{X,Y}$ and not $f_{X,XY}$.

Comment: Never the less, since $t<x<1$ and $u\leq x<1$, $t/u$ which is the change of variables for $y$ if I understand it correctly and thus also needs to be $<1$, but then I run into a problem when computing the integral where I obtain a $ln$ which is undefined for $0$. I probably need to split the integral somehow before evaluating it, so that it is $\int_0^? 1du+\int_?^x t/u du$.

Comment: Could it be $t$? I mean $$\int_0^x min(1,t/u)du=\int_0^t du+\int_t^x t/u du=xy-xy\cdot ln(y)$$